# Git "add --patch" is not working

Tags: windows, git

When I type `git add --patch` on my Windows 10 machine in the terminal, I get the error:

```
git: 'add--interactive' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

I've googled to no avail, all other problems seem to be people running into this issue using other software or on Linux. Any tips?

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Comment: git version 2.16.1.windows.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](https://forum.voidlinux.eu/t/solved-git-add-interactive-is-not-a-git-command/4516) (for Git on Linux) mentioned the lack of a `git-perl` package.

But that should not be the case on Windows.

For testing, download [`PortableGit-2.17.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.17.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.17.0-64-bit.7z.exe) and uncompress its content anywhere you want.

Then setup a simplified PATH:

```
set G=c:\path\to\latest\git
set PATH=%G%\bin;%G%\usr\bin;%G%\mingw64\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

In that CMD session, try again your `git add -p` command.

Comment: Running the git exe allows me to use the command, but when I use my; regular command prompt console (Console2), I still get the same issue. Do you know how I can set that up to work properly?

Comment: @mrcharlie you need to check your PATH within your Console2 shell

Comment: Ah it was pointing to the wrong folder `C:\Program Files\Git` instead of `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @mrcharlie possibly: try to emulate the PATH I recommend, with a portable Git nucompressed in a simpler PATH, without space.